# What does these UML diagram arrows mean in Iterator pattern?

Tags: uml, iterator

What does these UML diagram arrows mean in Iterator pattern that are drawn from `ConcreteAggregate` to `ConcreteIterator` and backwards. I have looked thorough the legend (notations) of UML diagrams, but I guess that was more confusing than explaining.

As much as I understand the arrows mean that `ConcreteAggregate` is dependent on `ConceteIterator`, and `ConcreteIterator` uses `ConceteAggregate`. But what does that clearly mean? What is the difference of `uses` and `depends on`?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this pattern?

Comment: Of course, GoF! :)

Comment: it's actually not UML but OMT

Comment: @Machado uml basically took Parts from OMT and made it better/more consistent. It's funny. Everybody knows GoF book, but nobody read the intro were they explain it ;-P

Comment: @Machado: Also, keep in mind that GoF is a twenty-two year-old book.

Comment: @Lovis, now I'll have to remove the dust of my GoF copy and check the intro. :) You're right, I guess I never read that. :) Robert, no problem, I'll read it into the proper context.

Comment: OMT was a strange choice 22 years ago because it had already been merged into UML 1.x for many years. Are you sure this book was first published 22 years ago?

Answer (score 3):

The Gang Of Four Book does not use UML but [OMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-modeling_technique) (or it's at least *based on* OMT)

- The dotted arrow means "instantiation", so it says that the `ConcreteAggregate` *creates* the `ConcreteIterator`.
- The normal arrow means containment (a weaker relationship than aggregation, so while it *knows* the other object it's not *responsible* for it's lifecycle).
  The `ConcreteIterator` *contains* a `ConcreteAggregate`. This is also visible in the displayed constructor call `return new ConcreteIterator(this)`

Source: The GoF Book

Comment: Excellent ! Indeed it's OMT as explained in appendix B. Note however that the authors explained that the dotted arriw notation is not part of the OMT and they took the freedom to add it to the notation. Also worthwhile mention that UML uses the same kind of notation to represent class dependencies, one of which being the instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

The class `ConcreteAggregate` depends on the class `ConcreteIterator` because the `CreateIterator()` method creates an instance of the `ConcreteIterator` class and returns it to the caller as an instance of the more general `Iterator` class.

The `ConcreteIterator` class has a constructor that is not shown on this diagram. What must be the case is that the `CreateIterator()` method is passing its own instance (i.e., `this`) as a parameter to that constructor. The `ConcreteIterator` class stores the reference that was passed to it as a member variable, shown in this UML diagram as a unidirectional association.

---

You didn't ask, but I will tell you that there are *many* problems with the UML on this diagram. *Therefore, do not use this book to learn UML!*

For example:

- The triangles shown on the generalization relations should be drawn at the *top* of the line, not on the *middle* of the line.
- The association arrowheads are supposed to be open (like `<--`).
- The associations do not show association-end properties, such as the one representing the member variable that the constructor for the `ConcreteIterator` class sets. I would expect to see something like `creatingAggregate` near the arrowhead.
- The associations do not show any multiplicity, which defaults to [1..1] in UML. That implies that an instance of the `Client` class must have a reference to an instance of the `Iterator` class *at all times*, which is obviously impossible. (An instance of `Client` must first call that `CreateIterator()` method to get that reference!) That multiplicity should have been optional [0..1].
- The `CreateIterator()` method shows no return type of `Iterator`.

Correcting some of these mistakes may have made this book more understandable for you.

Comment: GoF uses [OMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-modeling_technique) notation. so there is no "problem with the uml" since it's not uml.

Comment: Well, this question was tagged as "UML", but even for OMT it still has problems. Just one I can remember is that optional multiplicity is shown with a hollow ball at the end of an association.

Comment: Oh, I see you also came here xD

Comment: Indeed GoF in appendix B explain that it's OMT but that they took some liberties as for example the dotted arrow, because nothing in OMT could represent the instantiation dependency. So it's not UML but almost. By the way, are you sure that absence of multiplicity defaults to 1..1 ? Isn't it just unspecified ?

Comment: I am sure about the multiplicity because I have had to change a profile specification that wanted to default to 0..*.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcreteAggregate` has a compile-time dependency on `ConcreteIterator`, as shown in the code in the annotation box. The author of the diagram thought this dependency was important enough to show not only in the comment but also as the dashed arrow, a notation which can indicate any kind of dependency.

The two classes are also associated, indicated by the solid line. The association is one-directional (indicated by the arrow), meaning that `ConcreteIterator` is aware of the association but `ConcreteAggregate` is not. In practice, this means an instance of `ConcreteIterator` holds a reference to an instance of `ConcreteAggregate`.

This diagram is focused on the relationships that are relevant to the `CreateIterator()` operation. This first indication of this is the lack of any other responsibilities shown for `Aggregate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is still very confusing. :) I don't get the point.

Comment: @Narek: while this answer is correct, see if my answer makes any more sense to you.

Comment: Compile time is irrelevant in uml. UML models could be implemented with interpreted or dynamic languages as well.